# U-SQL using external Python packages

Tags: python, u-sql

If I download a Python package, will I be able to just import it inside of my U-SQL script?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but it requires a few steps:

- creating a zip file to hold you module
- uploading the zip to Azure Data Lake
- In your U-SQL script: using DEPLOY RESOURCE to make the zip available to your U-SQL code.
- In your Python code that is used by the U-SQL script. Modifying sys.path to include the zip

Here's full description of how to accomplish this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/03/10/using-custom-python-libraries-with-u-sql/